# User is not unsubscribing when having + in the email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, unsubscribe

Facing an issue, I noticed some cases where users are unable to unsubscribe if they have a + symbol in the email address.

Example - `abc+cd@gmail.com`

Does anyone have the same issue before? any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because `+` equates to a space when the email address is URL encoded.

Your custom preference center will need to be updated to replace all spaces with `+` characters.

SSJS:

```javascript
emailAddress = emailAddress.replace(" ","+");
```

AMPscript:

```ampscript
set @emailAddress = replace(@emailAddress," ","+")
```

Comment: Hey @Adam Spriggs you are amazing! Thanks for the quick help.